# Linux - Centos : Giving nginx chmod access

Tags: php, linux, centos, fuelphp

Alright so I cannot for the life of me get rid of this error :

```
Warning!

ErrorException [ Warning ]: chmod(): Operation not permitted

COREPATH/classes/finder.php @ line 511:

510:    {
511:    chmod($dir.$file, \Config::get('file.chmod.files', 0666));
512:    }
```

Here is my setup for permissions :

```
(775) : drwxrwxr-x myuser:nginx
```

Groups :

```
nginx:x:499:myuser,nginx
```

PHP-FPM Config

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

So this works for creating / editing files ect. and that all works fine.

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: Did nginx user create this file? Try Changing ownership of the file/folder to nginx user and group. `chown nginx:nginx nameoffile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because nginx had created a file, it has to be the owner.

Answer (score 2):

As root, try:

```
chown nginx:nginx /your/directory/to/fuel/ -R
```

Also don't forget to run inside the FuelPHP directory:

```
php oil r install
```

in order to make the necessary directories of FuelPHP writable

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs as `www-user` (or similar) - check your permissions against that.

Comment: Im running nginx php-fpm as :

 user = nginx
group = nginx

Comment: Try running `echo getmyuid();`

Comment: Also, check your intermediary directory permissions http://blog.yourlabs.org/day/2012/03/13

Comment: So it looks like my UID is 500 ...and uid=500(myuser) gid=500(myuser).. so its running as myuser rather than nginx user?

Comment: `exec` will run a shell, that's inaccurate for this case.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that's the best way; but I'm also not sure how to overcome this situation. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What is you full path to file you are chmod'ing ?

For example if its: /var/www/website/fuel/app/tmp/myfile.jpeg

try checking the permissions for:

ls -la /var/www/website/fuel/app/tmp/myfile.jpeg

ls -la /var/www/website/fuel/app/tmp

ls -la /var/www/website/fuel/app

ls -la /var/www/website/fuel

ls -la /var/www/website

ls -la /var/www

And compare them

If think some of parent directories are just not 'writeable by others'